# Create file for every script instance

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I've created the script below to obtain the folder size of C:\Users with the linux tool DU. The script is distributed via GPO to all users.

```
xcopy \\0.0.0.0\netlogon\gnu-core-utils\du.exe C:\profile-size-script\ /i /s /Y
xcopy \\0.0.0.0\netlogon\gnu-core-utils\libintl3.dll C:\profile-size-script\ /i /s /Y
xcopy \\0.0.0.0\netlogon\gnu-core-utils\libiconv2.dll C:\profile-size-script\ /i /s /Y
C:
cd C:\profile-size-script
du -hs C:\users\* > \\0.0.0.0\userfolder\%username%.txt
```

Lines are explained below:

1. Copies file called du.exe to location C:\profile-size-script
2. Copies file called libintl3.dll to same location.
3. Copies file called libiconv2.dll
4. Change to drive C: in case cmd starts at a different drive Letter.
5. Change to same folder size
6. Use DU to get the folder size and echo the output to \0.0.0.0\userfolder\%username%.txt.

The issue is that this script is not creating a new file for each user but is appending the firstly created file %username%.txt

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking to do something like this:

```
xcopy \\0.0.0.0\netlogon\gnu-core-utils\du.exe C:\profile-size-script\ /i /s /Y
xcopy \\0.0.0.0\netlogon\gnu-core-utils\libintl3.dll C:\profile-size-script\ /i /s /Y
xcopy \\0.0.0.0\netlogon\gnu-core-utils\libiconv2.dll C:\profile-size-script\ /i /s /Y
cd /d C:\profile-size-script
for /d %%u in (c:\users\*) do (du -hs C:\users\* > \\0.0.0.0\userfolder\%u%.txt)
```

The `FOR /D` loop reads through each of the folders and executes your `du.exe` command for each folder (`%%u`) it finds.  Check out `FOR /?` for more information and other possibilities.

Additional note:  the `CD /D` command allows you to change drive letter and directory at the same time.  Alternately, you can skip the `C:` and `CD` lines altogether if you run your commands without even changing directory using the explicit path like this:

```
xcopy...
for /d %%u in (c:\users\*) do (
    C:\profile-size-script\du.exe -hs C:\users\* > \\0.0.0.0\userfolder\%u%.txt)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply Wes. I did use the `CD /D` however I solved my issue using my solution belo.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a new file as the answer recommended would create a txt file for every folder in C:\users*.

```
xcopy \\0.0.0.0\netlogon\gnu-core-utils\du.exe C:\profile-size-script\ /i /s /Y
xcopy \\0.0.0.0\netlogon\gnu-core-utils\libintl3.dll C:\profile-size-script\ /i /s /Y
xcopy \\0.0.0.0\netlogon\gnu-core-utils\libiconv2.dll C:\profile-size-script\ /i /s /Y
cd /d C:\profile-size-script
copy NUL \\0.0.0.0\userfolder\%username%.txt
du -hs C:\users\* > \\0.0.0.0\userfolder\%username%.txt
```

Everytime the script is run it copies a NUL file and renames it according to the logged on user, which does the trick for me. I did however replace the `C:` with `cd /d` (Which changes drive and directory).